# ClickOnce Windows Forms application is throwing an exception on attempt to update via CheckForDetailedUpdate()

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2008, deployment, clickonce

I have a [Windows Forms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Forms) ClickOnce application that performs its own application updates.  This has been working fine for several years, however, a recent deployment is producing the following exception:

```
Message: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
Source: System.Deployment
Target Site: System.Security.Policy.ApplicationTrust RequestTrust(System.Deployment.Application.SubscriptionState, Boolean, Boolean, System.ActivationContext, System.Security.Policy.TrustManagerContext)
Stack Trace:    at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationTrust.RequestTrust(SubscriptionState subState, Boolean isShellVisible, Boolean isUpdate, ActivationContext actCtx, TrustManagerContext tmc)
   at System.Deployment.Application.DeploymentManager.DetermineTrustCore(Boolean blocking, TrustParams tp)
   at System.Deployment.Application.DeploymentManager.DetermineTrust(TrustParams trustParams)
   at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationDeployment.CheckForDetailedUpdate(Boolean persistUpdateCheckResult)
   at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationDeployment.CheckForDetailedUpdate()
   at SCANit.Inventory.ClickOnce.CheckForDetailedUpdate()
   at SCANit.Inventory.AppUpdaterService.StatusOfUpdate(Boolean notify)
   at SCANit.Inventory.AppUpdaterService.PerformAppUpdate()
   at SCANitApp.MainApplication.updateMenuItem_ItemClick(Object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
```

My attempts to search the error reveals it's possibly due to an expired certificate, .pfx. However, I generated a certificate with a long expiry date. I did a diff in [Git](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Git_%28software%29) on the previous deployment's .pfx and application .csproj and see no real differences. What might be happening here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My apologies, I found a difference in the .csproj file I did not catch before:

```
<PlatformTarget>x86</ PlatformTarget>
```

This seems to have fixed it when changing to AnyCpu for the application.